# Different Tabs based on different Roles in iOS (Objective-C)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller

I have a project that is not using Storyboards. When the app first starts up, it loads a screen for login and sign up. After logging in, I want it to load a Tab Bar Controller with Tabs based on the login from the earlier screen.

At this moment, in my AppDelegate.m, I loaded the view controller, Profile. If the user is not logged in, a login and sign up view controller pops up (as a modal). Upon signing in, this login and sign up view controller pops down, and returns to Profile but now with a Tab Bar Controller. However, the Tab Bars cannot be loaded based on the role of the user.

I started off with Parse's Login and Sign Up View which can be downloaded here: https://parse.com/tutorials/login-and-signup-views.

Anyone with any idea? Thanks, and sample code appreciated!

Comment: What's the problem ? I don't understand the question

Comment: @Euwing: can you please explain what exactly you want to do with these tab bars